# SQL Server Replication Monitor Throwing "Specified cast is not valid. (ReplicationMonitor)" Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, replication

The publisher is running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Server 2008 R2 box. The subscriber is running SQL Server 2012 on a Server 2012 box. I have tried launching the replication monitor from both servers but can't drill down into details on either instance.

[image]

Any ideas on what is going wrong here? I really need to be able to drill down into the details of each description

Comment: It looks like you have a corrupt installation.  Have you tried running repair?

Comment: What type of replication you have ?

Comment: A combination of transactional and snapshot replication. I am going to try running repair and report back with those results

Comment: Installing windows updates and running repair on the 2012 instance did not help